# How to output from Select statement only if all rows have the same value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get a select statement to output **only** if all columns in a table selection have the same value.

Here's the example:

The table below has the same values (`name`, `age`) for each `ruleid`. `Data` value changes with each row (`True`/`False`).

I want to be able to select from rule table where `ruleid = '27460'` and ONLY write to output if all the selected `data` values are `True` for that `ruleid`.

In the example table below all rows with `ruleid 27460` have `data = 'True'` except for one row - so no output.  If they were all `True` then output should be one line for that `ruleid`.

```
ruleid    name    age
27460     Bob     99  

Rule
+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+
| ruleid      | data         | name       | age   | 
+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+
| 27460       | True         | Bob        | 99    |
| 27488       | True         | Sue        | 23    |
| 27460       | True         | Bob        | 99    |
| 27460       | True         | Bob        | 99    |
| 27460       | False        | Bob        | 99    |
| 27460       | True         | Bob        | 99    |
| 27488       | True         | Sue        | 23    |
| 27460       | True         | Bob        | 99    |
+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: So "no output" or "27460 Bob 99"? Did you mean "27488 Sue 23"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can go for the below query

```
select *
    from rule r1
    where r1.ruleid = 27460
    and r1.data = (select r2.data from rule r2 where 
    r2.data='True' and r1.data = r2.data)
    limit 1;
```

Comment: With the above select statement won't it still output if there's a row with data='False' (even though there are other True rows)?  If any of the selected rows with ruleid=27460 have a 'False' in data then it shouldn't output anything.

Comment: it wont because i have put and data=True

Comment: But if data='True' in any of the result I don't want output.  If data = 'False' for all ruleid rows then I want output.

Comment: then just make and data='False" in above query ...thats it...but in question you have " If they were all True then output should be one line for that ruleid." so i thought you want only True rows..

Comment: Sorry, you're correct.  The objective is to test all data for a ruleid  are equal to the same value (e.g. True) with no exceptions.  If so then output, otherwise no output.  With the select above it looks like if there's at least one 'True' it will output.  I need all rows with ruleid='27460' to have the same 'data' value in order to have an output.  Thank you for your patience with me.

Comment: I think that works!! Thank you. Can I add one more twist? Add another table 'hash' that has rows containing the ruleid and data values.    E.g. TABLE: HASH with rows(ruleid, data) values(27460,True, 27460, False, 27488, False, 28456,True).     Each row's values (ruleid and data) would be input to your select statement above and output, at most, one result per row for each entry in this HASH table.